# SASL Authentication failure

Tags: centos, authentication, pam, smtp, sasl

Created an user with

```
# adduser username
```

The configuration file /etc/sysconfig/saslauthd:

```
# Directory in which to place saslauthd's listening socket, pid file, and so
# on.  This directory must already exist.
SOCKETDIR=/run/saslauthd

# Mechanism to use when checking passwords.  Run "saslauthd -v" to get a list
# of which mechanism your installation was compiled with the ablity to use.
MECH=pam

# Additional flags to pass to saslauthd on the command line.  See saslauthd(8)
# for the list of accepted flags.
FLAGS=-r
```

But it's not working.

```
# testsaslauthd -u username -p password -s smtp
0: NO "authentication failed"
```

This is the error shown by `journalctl -u saslauthd`:

```
dic 08 20:34:22 xxxx.com saslauthd[11847]: DEBUG: auth_pam: pam_authenticate failed: Authentication failure
dic 08 20:34:22 xxxx.com saslauthd[11847]: do_auth         : auth failure: [user=username] [service=smtp] [realm=] [mech=pam] [reason=PAM auth error]
```

Comment: You can add the debugging option `-d` in the FLAGS section which should produce more informative logging.  Unfortunately, these sorts of problems tend to be difficult to diagnose from across the Internet.  There are many moving parts to the configuration... such as:  properly setting the hostname, adding your smtp provider to the `sasl` group, restarting authentication services, making sure that the permissions are correct for the creation of socket connection... and many other details minor and major.... but `debugging` mode is a good place to start.